Big Query Updating Table using a Self-Join
`I am working on my portfolio project from Alex the Analyst youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rO7ztF4NtU at around minute 17:55. I am working on Bigquery while he does his project on MySQL server.'
I am trying to update the column PropertyAddress in my table 'mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN' to replace the nulls with values in a self-join based off of the Unique IDs of the properties closed.
I tried his code below straight form the video and that did not work. It gave me the following error. "Column name PropertyAddress is ambiguous at [7:7]"
UPDATE `mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN`
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL (A.PropertyAddress, B.PropertyAddress)
FROM `mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN` A
JOIN `mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN` B
  ON A.ParcelID = B.ParcelID
  AND A.UniqueID_ <> B.UniqueID_
WHERE PropertyAddress is null

So I did the following and I am getting an error as well "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"
UPDATE `mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN`
SET PropertyAddress = 
(
SELECT
IFNULL (A.PropertyAddress, B.PropertyAddress)
FROM `mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN` A
JOIN `mineral-service-407123.HousingData.HomePurchaseTN` B
  ON A.ParcelID = B.ParcelID
  AND A.UniqueID_ <> B.UniqueID_
)
WHERE PropertyAddress is null

I am not sure what to do because I have tried to modify it in many different ways. I normally am able to do the commands as he does in MySQL but with a little modification because it is BigQuery. Not sure what to do here because I have been stuck on this for quite some time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The video demonstrates the use of ms sql server, not mysql. Bigquery, ms sql server and mysql are all different database products with different implementations of sql. Please do not ever rely on an ms sql server related video for help on bigquery related problems.

I understand that. Accidentally used the wrong server name, it is a different server from bigquery though. Any issues that I have had with the difference in servers I have been able to resolve it.
